# Get PHP echo data to be captilized

Tags: php

So I've successfully managed to get a movie title and video title to display via the following code. My question is how do I force the first letters of the output to be captilized?

I know is CSS you would do something along the lines of {text-transform:capitalize;} but how do you implement this sort of thing in PHP?

```
<?php echo  $movtitle.' '.$vidtitle;?>
```

Comment: What, like `ucfirst($movtitle)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo  ucwords($movtitle.' '.$vidtitle);?>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

You could've googled that easily!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [the `ucwords()` function in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upper case the first character of *each* word, use [ucwords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), or you can use [ucfirst](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) (for just the initial character in the string) or [strtoupper](http://www.php.net/strtoupper) to upper-case the *entire* string.

Incidentally, it's worth getting to know the various PHP [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) (and indeed [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)), as time invested in this now will pay dividends later.